# Log4j2 configurationFile system property only working during maven tests

Tags: xml, maven, log4j2, maven-surefire-plugin

I've been struggling a lot to get this working. Log4j2 documentation asks to define a `log4j.configurationFile` system property to define a custom configuration path. I defined this property in my `pom.xml`

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.18.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/RequestMetricsTest.java</exclude>
            <exclude>**/SessionMetricsTest.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
        <systemProperties>
            <property>
                 <name>log4j.configurationFile</name>
                 <value>src/main/resources/metrics-log4j2.xml</value>
            </property>
        </systemProperties>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

this works perfect when I run `mvn install` which executes the test cases and logs in to the file I defined in the configuration. However when I replace this built jar in my web-app it fails to log anything and keeps throwing the error about log4j2 configuration xml not found.

**Question**: Is there anywhere else I need to define this system property?

NOTE: I do not have `web.xml` in my project.

Comment: where are you setting the systemProperties section above? in the surefire maven plugin? Could you please share more of your POM file?

Comment: yes it is defined in surefire maven plugin. Update the question. Please take look.

Comment: than it's normal that only applied to the test phase. Is there any reason why is must be called metrics-log4j2.xml and not log4j2.xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are specifying the system property as part of the Maven Surefire Plugin, which only applies to executed tests, that's why the configuration was not visible for your final application.

However, the configuration file is placed under `/src/main/resources`, hence it will still be shipped (packaged) with the project artifact. But it does not have a standard (default) name and as such Log4j 2 needs a further parameter to point at it.

From the [official F.A.Q. page](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/faq.html#config_location):

> By default, Log4j looks for a configuration file named `log4j2.xml` (not `log4j.xml`) in the classpath.
> You can also specify the full path of the configuration file with this system property:
> `-Dlog4j.configurationFile=path/to/log4j2.xml`

If you want to apply it to your web application, according to [official documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/webapp.html#ContextParams), you should add to the following to you `web.xml` file

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfiguration</param-name>
    <param-value>/metrics-log4j2.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

But since you mentioned you don't have a `web.xml` file in your project (how come?) you could simply rename it to its default name (from `metrics-log4j2.xml` to `log4j2.xml`) and should be recognized automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Actually, the part of the project I'm working at doesn't require web.xml. Of course there is a web.xml for the entire project. With your explanation I make out that I need to make change in that web.xml. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

The Surefire plugin is only used during the test phase of the build lifecycle. System properties set here are meant only for injecting during the Maven build rather than when the application is running.

Once you compile and run your JAR, this will use the system properties of the host or those you pass as parameters.

Say you are running your JAR like:

```
java -jar myjar.jar
```

You can set the log4j property:

```
java -Dlog4j.configurationFile=src/main/resources/metrics-log4j2.xml -jar myjar.jar
```

> On a side note:

`systemProperties` is deprecated.

Can you please try with `systemPropertyVariables` instead.

Documentation available here:
https://maven.apache.org/components/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/system-properties.html

Comment: Okay, I'll make that change and try. But a few questions, Why does it work for maven tests if it is deprecated? and, adding this in `pom.xml` is enough for getting the log working? Sorry for these noob questions. I'm doing this for the first time.

Comment: it will not work anyway, it will keep on be applied only to the test phase

Comment: Updated answer with required info. Sorry I hit save too soon!